# Are non-Japanese political party names translated, or transliterated?

Tags: loanwords

Are the names of new political parties, especially in English-speaking countries, typically translated, or transliterated?

I looked at the Japanese language Wikipedia template for Australian political parties, and saw that Family First seemed to be translated (家族優先党), while the Australian Sex Party and One Nation seemed to be transliterated (オーストラリアセックス党 and ワン・ネイション) apart from the "党".

**Background:** Australia's Liberal Democratic Party looks like it might win a seat, and I'm curious whether it'd be called "自由民主党", as is claimed by the Japanese edition of Wikipedia [here](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%87%AA%E7%94%B1%E6%B0%91%E4%B8%BB%E5%85%9A_%28%E6%9B%96%E6%98%A7%E3%81%95%E5%9B%9E%E9%81%BF%29).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically they are translated. For American parties, as an example, Japanese newspapers always write 民主党 for the Democrats and 共和党 for the Republicans. Communist parties everywhere are 共産党. You will refer to a Labo(u)r Party as 労働党. Even the Green Party gets a 緑の党 designation. There are exceptions, of course. For example, the Libertarian Party is just called リバタリアン党 rather than 自由党 (which is already claimed as the "liberal party").

Take a look [here](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AB%E3%81%AE%E6%94%BF%E5%85%9A). It's a list of American parties only but it should give you a big enough list to get a feel for how party names are translated.